# How can you check if a function in jQuery is empty?

Tags: jquery, function

How would you check if the function that does exist and is defined, is empty or not? For example:

```
function foo(){
   // empty
}

function bar(){
   alert('something');
   // not empty
}
```

Is there a function or a a simple way to check this?

Comment: What would the practical use be?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in a JQuery way to do it? (JQuery != JS)

Comment: @Nico, well no, JS would of course also be fine. I just thought there would maybe be a jQuery function in existence already that I was overlooking.

Comment: @Juhana, checking if user assigned callbacks in my jQuery plugin meet requirements.

Comment: That's a quite... peculiar requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really very useful, and generally not a good idea, but you could do:

```
function foo(){

}

function bar(){
   alert('something');
   // not empty
}

console.log('foo is empty :' + isEmpty(foo));
console.log('bar is empty :' + isEmpty(bar));

function isEmpty(f) {
  return typeof f === "function" && /^function [^(]*\(\)[ ]*{(.*)}$/.exec(
     f.toString().replace(/\n/g, "")
   )[1].trim() === "";
}​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8gWn5/)

If it's just to check a callback, the normal way would be just to check if the callback is a function:

```
if (typeof callback === 'function') callback.call();
```

**EDIT:**

To also disregard comments :

```
function isEmpty(f) {
  return typeof f === "function" && /^function [^(]*\(\)[ ]*{(.*)}$/.exec(
     f.toString().replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\<![\-\-\s\w\>\/]*\>)/g, '')
   )[1].trim() === "";
}​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8gWn5/2/)

Comment: Nice, but won't work if there are comments inside the function.

Comment: No it won't, and then the function would'nt really be empty either!

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer! Guess there isn't a simple way to check and i'll just check if the callback is indeed a function.

Answer (score 1):

A function could be empty but still be passed variables.  This would error in adeneo's function:

```
function bar(t) { }
```

Modifying the regex, here is the same function with support for variables:

```
function isEmpty(f) {
  return typeof f === "function" && /^function [^(]*\([^)]\)[ ]*{(.*)}$/.exec(
     f.toString().replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\<![\-\-\s\w\>\/]*\>)/g, '')
   )[1].trim() === "";
}​
```